# Is there a VBA function to copy a shape picture to the background?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm struggling with VBA in PowerPoint. I have many vertical portrait photos in my slides. I want to change the background of the slide to the specific portrait (and make it blur), to get rid of the white borders. Manually it’s quite simple per slide, just copy the photo object, go to Format Background, change the fill to picture or texture fill and click under picture source for “Clipboard”. Then choose under artistic effects for blur.

I want to automate these steps for all slides by using VBA, because there are so many pictures changing every month.

I tried the “.Shapes("Portrait").Copy” function, but there is no paste in the .Background.Fill.UserPicture I think.
I tried the following, but that doesn’t work:

```
Sub ChangeBackground()
With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange

      .Shapes("Portrait").Copy
     .FollowMasterBackground = msoFalse
     '.Background.Fill.UserPicture ("C:\temp\test.jpg")
     .Background.Fill.UserPicture .Shapes("Portrait").Copy
     .Background.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert msoEffectBlur
            
End With
End Sub
```

Do you have any idea if this is even possible?
I don’t want to select a file from disk, because the portraits are not stored on disk.

Comment: Not all user interface commands are included in the VBA object model. You've found one of them. A background picture can be inserted from the clipboard using the program interface, but not from VBA.

Instead, you would have to save the photo on the selected slide as a file, then insert that file as a background.

Comment: Thank you John. I was already prepared for this answer as I can't find anything related to this clipboard functionality. Thanks for your prompt help